# PHP - How to set an email title with CURLOPT_PUT?

Tags: php, curl

I am working on a cron job that implements email functionality.
It essentially sends out email reports.

I am able to send out an email using CURLOPT_PUT as follows:

```
//create email body etc
$to = 'dennis.kozevnikoff@outlook.com';
$server = 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465';
$message = 'test message';
$emailFile = fopen("php://temp", 'w+');
fwrite($emailFile, $message);
rewind($emailFile);
$fstat = fstat($emailFile);
$size = $fstat['size'];

//initialize and authenticate cURL
$ch = curl_init($server); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'd.kozevnikoff@outlook.com' . ':' . 'samplepass');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, array("<" . $to . ">"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $emailFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $size);

fclose($emailFile);
curl_close($ch);
```

The issue is that I am not able to set the title (a.k.a subject) of the email, it arrives as "No Subject".
Is it possible to get this done using my current set up, and if so, how can I achieve that?

I am aware that CURLOPT_POST can achieve this, but that causes me other issues, and is not an option for me at the moment.

Comment: If you're doing a raw SMTP connection then you're going to have to ensure your message is formatted according to the RFC, which is a world of headache you likely do not want. I'd just use something like SwiftMailer or PHPMailer.

Comment: Email subject is not part of the SMTP protocol but a header of the email message itself. Headers are sent after you're done with SMTP commands and they're just part of the message, separated by `\r\n` from the message body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix the issue. You can add a subject (title) to the email by pre-appending the second argument of the fwrite() function as follows:

```
$subject = "email title";
fwrite($emailFile, "Subject: " . $subject . "\n" . $message);
```

However, as others suggested, if you can, it is better to use more modern libraries like SwiftMailer or PHP Mailer to achieve this functionality since CURLOPT_PUT has been deprecated.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the RFCs define `\r\n` as the line break for headers, and you need _two_ line breaks to divide headers and body content. Which is a hilariously small taste of the exact brand of esoteric nerdery required to send emails reliably. Use a library where the nerds already took care of the nerdery.